# few line chart's Legend is being display

Tags: angular, highcharts, linechart

Hi I am using line chart and highcharts version 8.0.0

i observe one issue here-
I am sending array of 2 data in series but graph is showing only one legend which will misguide to user that it has only one data-

```
    this.dateHeaderArray = ['Jan 2021', 'Feb 2021', 'Mar 2021', 'Apr 2021', 'May 2021', 'Jun 2021', 'Jul 2021', 'Aug 2021', 'Sep 2021', 'Oct 2021', 'Nov 2021', 'Dec 2021'];

this.seriesDataArray = [
    {
        "name": "a_c5af-4825-86df-bc5_7161-4142-ad77-04d",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [ null,null,null,null,null,null,null, null, null, null,null,null],
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "a_c5af-4825-86df-bc5_47b6-4616-a20b-dc3",
        "type": "line",
        "data": [ null,null,null,null,null,null,null, null, null, null,null,null],
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    }
];
this.chartOptions = {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.3f}</b>'
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Score',
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: '#485465'
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      rotation: 0,
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: '#485465'
      },
    },
    categories: this.dateHeaderArray
  },
  series: this.seriesDataArray
};
```

can someone suggest on this , is that version issue or configuration and if it is version issue then what version will work proper for my case.

image url- https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6t23.jpg

Comment: tmage url for how graph is showing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6t23.jpg

Comment: Hi @Shikha Shrivastav, I have used your code with Highcharts 8.0.0 and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3t875gn0/ Could you recreate the issue in some online code editor?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek i have attched the image url. can you please open this that how exactly i am receiving

Comment: The problem is clear, but I can not reproduce it. Please provide me with a link to some online code editor with the reproduced issue.

Comment: actually i am receiving this.seriesDataArray  from backend which value is varying according to response-

Comment: i think the issue is with update the chart

Comment: first time graph is being show proper but when new response is updated on chart options , all of the series is not being show. the problem is with update highchart. can you please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

after some search I found the solution and the reason of getting wrong result.

how the update function work in highchart -

> ```
> update(options [, redraw] [, oneToOne] [, animation])
> ```

an id option is used to map the new option set to an existing object. If an existing object of the same id is not found, the corresponding item (which is in same index) is updated.
Here oneToOne play a good role. since if oneToOne is true then collections will be updated one to one, and items will be either added or removed to match the new updated options.

> [oneToOne]="true" has solved the issue like below -

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" [oneToOne]="true" [(update)]="gotScorecardData">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is working as expected for the first time and not working post update, try adding update flag as below.

```
<highcharts-chart[Highcharts]="Highcharts"[options]="chartOptions"[(update)]="updateFlag"></highcharts-chart>
```

And set the flag to true whenever you are updating the series data.

```
this.updateFlag = true;
```

Comment: I tired reproducing your issue but working as expected for me, need more explanation

Comment: if you are able to see the data on console then just try if any styling issue with the legends, may be try at a different layout just to make sure the legend is appearing there